# In PHP 7.4+, do contravarying parameters make sense when the parent / superclass's parameter is untyped?

Tags: php, types, parameters, interface

Consider an interface like

```
interface Validator { validate($x) : bool }
```

implemented classes would ideally allow typed parameters:

```
class ValidatorPositiveInteger(int $x);
class ValidatorAlphabetic(string $x);
```

The compiler currently does not allow typing of the parameters for the concrete classes due to the parameter widening aspect of the Liskov substitution principle.  But is this restriction really necessary or desirable when the interface / parent class places no restriction on the parameter type?  Is this interface a 'bad interface' because the validate method does not specify a parameter type?